# Using vb.net to store data via xml practice

Tags: xml, vb.net

I started this as a self-teaching exercise and now I'm stumped. I would very much appreciate it if anyone can help me learn, through walking me through my to-be-explained exercise and the necessary content.

I have written a very basic, visual basic app, that functions as follows:

- Accept text input through text boxes
- Save button stores information in xml file
- Clear button removes information from text boxes
- Retrieve button reads information from xml file and displays data in text boxes

Graphically my form has 4 text boxes paired with 4 labels marked as follows:

- Name
- Color
- Number
- Zip Code

It then has 3 buttons, one to save the data, one to clear the data(from the form, not xml file), and one to retrieve the data(re-display in text boxes).

Here is my code so far:

```
    Imports System.Xml

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Save_Data(Optional ByVal name As String = "", Optional ByVal color As String = "", Optional ByVal number As String = "", Optional ByVal zipcode As String = "")
        Dim writer As New XmlTextWriter("saved_data.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
        Try
            writer.WriteStartDocument(True)
            writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
            writer.Indentation = 2

            writer.WriteStartElement("Saved_Data")
            If Not txtName.Text = "" Then
                writer.WriteStartElement("name")
                writer.WriteString(name)
                writer.WriteEndElement()
            End If
            If Not txtColor.Text = "" Then
                writer.WriteStartElement("color")
                writer.WriteString(color)
                writer.WriteEndElement()
            End If
            If Not txtNumber.Text = "" Then
                writer.WriteStartElement("number")
                writer.WriteString(number)
                writer.WriteEndElement()
            End If
            If Not txtZipCode.Text = "" Then
                writer.WriteStartElement("zipcode")
                writer.WriteString(zipcode)
                writer.WriteEndElement()
            End If
                writer.WriteEndElement()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error storing the data!" + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + "Error: " + ex.Message)
        Finally
            writer.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Retrieve_Data()
        Dim reader As New XmlTextReader("saved_data.xml")
        Try
            While reader.Read()
                reader.ReadStartElement("Saved_Data")

                If Not reader.IsEmptyElement Then
                    reader.ReadStartElement("name")
                    txtName.Text = reader.ReadString()
                    reader.ReadEndElement()
                End If

                If Not reader.IsEmptyElement Then
                    reader.ReadStartElement("color")
                    txtColor.Text = reader.ReadString()
                    reader.ReadEndElement()
                End If

                If Not reader.IsEmptyElement Then
                    reader.ReadStartElement("number")
                    txtNumber.Text = reader.ReadString()
                    reader.ReadEndElement()
                End If

                If Not reader.IsEmptyElement Then
                    reader.ReadStartElement("zipcode")
                    txtZipCode.Text = reader.ReadString()
                    reader.ReadEndElement()
                End If

                reader.ReadEndElement()

            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error retrieving the data!" + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + "Error: " + ex.Message)
        Finally
            reader.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        Dim strName As String = txtName.Text
        Dim strColor As String = txtColor.Text
        Dim strNumber As String = txtNumber.Text
        Dim strZipCode As String = txtZipCode.Text

        Save_Data(strName, strColor, strNumber, strZipCode)

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        txtName.Text = ""
        txtColor.Text = ""
        txtNumber.Text = ""
        txtZipCode.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnRetrieve_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRetrieve.Click
        Retrieve_Data()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Please keep in mind, I have never worked with xml before, thusly I may not understand the vb.net side of it as well.

My end goal for this project is to create an "auto-save" structure to be used on a larger project. Where it saves either on a timer, or AS you type in the text boxes. So that you may click the "clear" button at any time, then click the "retrieve" button to restore from the last saved data.

My current issue is this: "Error: 'EndElement' is an invalid XmlNodeType. Line 6, position 3."
This error occurs while retrieving the data. When I add a quick watch to the error, it points me to whichever block that handles the data, input from the text box which I leave blank while saving the data.

The following is the xml result, produced after the error above appears. I have left the "Zip Code" text box blank.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Saved_Data>
  <name>Tony</name>
  <color>purple</color>
  <number>20</number>
  <zipcode />
</Saved_Data>
```

Thanks in advance for any help, I look forward to learning this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to learn is to keep your code [DRY, that is - don't repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). If you notice your code becomes boring and you can barely tell what each block is doing, because it's so much similar to the previous one - this is it. Stop and refactor. There is always a way to make code better, if you are willing to invest time into it.

Reading XML in your case can be accomplished with fewer lines of code (LINQ-to-XML):

```
Dim xDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("saved_data.xml")
With xDoc.Root
  txtName.Text = .Element("name").Value
  txtColor.Text = .Element("color").Value
  txtNumber.Text = .Element("number").Value
  txtZipCode.Text = .Element("zipcode").Value
End With
```

As your XML structure becomes more complicated, the approach you've taken would become a maintenance nightmare. [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx), however is very flexible and specifically built to handle complex cases. Using LINQ-to-XML approach, you can make read process very simple, even as your XML hierarchy expands into several deeply nested nodes.

I'll leave writing to XML as a homework for you. Give it a shot, should be very easy from the example I've given above. Let me know if you need help with it.

Comment: Thank for the elegance of your answer! I appreciate the example as well as study-support orientation. Like I have mentioned before, I have been working with vb.net for a while now, but I am still a novice when it comes to incorporating external programs and/or languages. I would vote this answer up, but I lack the ability... :-(

Comment: @Cody: You are welcome! Should be able to upvote at 15 reputation, and you are almost there! :) You can still accept my answer, if you feel like it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your Retrieve_Data method with this:

```
Private Sub Retrieve_Data()
        Dim reader As New XmlTextReader("c:\\d.xml")
        Try
            While reader.Read()
                reader.ReadStartElement("Saved_Data")

                reader.ReadStartElement("name")
                If Not reader.IsEmptyElement Then
                    txtName.Text = reader.ReadString()
                End If
                reader.ReadEndElement()

                reader.ReadStartElement("color")
                If Not reader.IsEmptyElement Then
                    txtColor.Text = reader.ReadString()
                End If
                reader.ReadEndElement()

                reader.ReadStartElement("number")
                If Not reader.IsEmptyElement Then
                    txtNumber.Text = reader.ReadString()
                End If
                reader.ReadEndElement()

                reader.ReadStartElement("zipcode")
                If Not reader.IsEmptyElement Then
                    txtZipCode.Text = reader.ReadString()
                End If
                reader.ReadEndElement()

                If Not reader.ReadState = ReadState.EndOfFile Then
                    reader.ReadEndElement()
                End If
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error retrieving the data!" + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + "Error: " + ex.Message)
        Finally
            reader.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Pay attention to the fact that each block has changed, and also the extra code around the final read...

Comment: Thank you Martin for responding! I agree with the way you restructured the ReadStartElement blocks. I had the same structure earlier today but though troubleshooting I changed it up. I did not know about the "reader.ReadState" thank you for bringing that to my attention!
Unfortunately I still receive the error mentioned above..

Comment: I forgot to mention something! If I manually edit the xml file shown above to read <zipcode></zipcode> instead of <zipcode /> it will run without error. I am assuming the issue lies within the shorthand process.

Comment: It ran without error on my machine with my code... Strange that you're having problems. You might also want to have a look at XLinq - XDocument, XElement and friends...

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and thanks for the help *All*.
As I needed to save more values and the elements in the form was unknown, I wrote class for saving and loading all data. "text" field is easy to save/load. Meawhile "Checkbox" is a bit tricky:

```
Public Class XMLAS
    Public Shared Sub Load_All_MyForms(forma As Object)
        Dim ctrl As Control = Nothing
        ctrl = forma.GetNextControl(ctrl, True)
        Try
            Dim reader As New XmlTextReader("C:\Users\User\Desktop\saved_data.xml")
            Try
                While reader.Read()
                    reader.ReadStartElement(XmlConvert.EncodeName("HASH_" + forma.GetHashCode.ToString))

                    Do Until ctrl Is Nothing
                        If (TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox) Or (TypeOf ctrl Is RichTextBox) Then
                            reader.ReadStartElement(XmlConvert.EncodeName(ctrl.Name))
                            ctrl.Text = XmlConvert.DecodeName(reader.ReadString())
                            reader.ReadEndElement()
                        Else If TypeOf ctrl Is CheckBox Then
                            reader.ReadStartElement(XmlConvert.EncodeName(ctrl.Name))
                            If XmlConvert.DecodeName(reader.ReadString()) = "1" Then
                                CType(ctrl, CheckBox).Checked = True
                            Else
                                CType(ctrl, CheckBox).Checked = False
                            End If
                            reader.ReadEndElement()
                        End If

                        ctrl = forma.GetNextControl(ctrl, True)
                    Loop
                    reader.ReadEndElement()
                End While
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("There was an error retrieving the data!" + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + "Error: " + ex.Message)
            Finally
                reader.Close()
            End Try
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub Save_All_MyForms(forma As Object)
        Dim ctrl As Control = Nothing
        ctrl = forma.GetNextControl(ctrl, True)
        Try
            Dim writer As New XmlTextWriter("C:\Users\User\Desktop\saved_data.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
            Try
                writer.WriteStartDocument(True)
                writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
                writer.Indentation = 2
                writer.WriteStartElement(XmlConvert.EncodeName("HASH_" + forma.GetHashCode.ToString))
                Do Until ctrl Is Nothing
                    If (TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox) Or (TypeOf ctrl Is RichTextBox) Then 'AndAlso ctrl.Name <> "cmdClose" Then

                        '        If Not txtName.Text = "" Then
                        writer.WriteStartElement(XmlConvert.EncodeName(ctrl.Name))
                        writer.WriteString(XmlConvert.EncodeName(ctrl.Text))
                        writer.WriteEndElement()
                        '        End If
                    Else If TypeOf ctrl Is CheckBox Then
                      writer.WriteStartElement(XmlConvert.EncodeName(ctrl.Name))
                        If CType(ctrl, CheckBox).Checked = True Then
                            writer.WriteString(XmlConvert.EncodeName("1"))
                        Else
                            writer.WriteString(XmlConvert.EncodeName("0"))
                        End If
                        writer.WriteEndElement()
                    End If
                    ctrl = forma.GetNextControl(ctrl, True)
                Loop
                writer.WriteEndElement()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Finally
                writer.Close()
            End Try

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
    ...
```

Now, all you need to do when you want to save: `XMLAS.Save_All_MyForms(Me)`
Or load: `XMLAS.Load_All_MyForms(Me)`.
Do not to forget to encode all the strings, or else it is possible to screw the XML.

Comment: XML text reader is useless in real word as it is "forward only reader, it simply can't go back.". Just make XML file a bit more "flexible" and all data is unreadable using this.
I am using writer to create xml document, but for reading I am using "GetElementsByTagName", "ParentNode.Name", "FirstChild.Value" to parse xml and search needed values.